# Accessing Bundle of main application while running XCTests

Tags: swift, bundle, xctest, nstask

In tests `target -> General -> Testing: set Host Application to None`, so that no app gets launched.

But in that case I cannot use `Bundle.main.resourcePath` and access resources of my main application (in which some command files are included as resources and I need to run them using `Process()`).

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added file to '**Copy Bundle Resources**' of **Test target** also, then used following code to get path for resource , instead of `"\(Bundle.main.resourcePath!)/test.command"`

`let testBundle =  Bundle(for: type(of: self))
 let path =  "\(testBundle.resourcePath!)/test.command""`

Answer (score 1):

`Bundle(identifier: "com.something.app")` will get you the bundle for a specific bundle ID. The problem is that if your bundle ID changes for your main target this will fail.

You can also try getting the bundle for a specific class:

`let bundle = Bundle(for: SomeClass.self)`

Where `SomeClass` is a class in your main bundle.

Comment: I had tried 'Bundle(identifier: mainappbundleid)', but while test target is run, this gives nil, and 'Bundle(for: SomeClass.self)'  gives bundle of test target itself.

Comment: I am still stuck. While test target is run, will the main app bundle load (since host app is set to none) ? may be thats why Bundle(identifier) gives nil ?